# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+a}}-\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+b}}\right)=\frac{b-a}2.$

Tags: limits

How can I prove the following statement:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+a}}-\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+b}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(b-a)\ for\ a,b>0$$

Comment: In your second equality you said that $x-y=x^2-y^2$??? Whatever property you use there It is totally wrong

Comment: In fact none of the equalities are correct, you sould check your basic algebra. Once you do the algebra the limit should be inmediate

Comment: Hint (you'll have to flesh out certain steps): since$$\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}=\frac{(b-a)/n^2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}}\sim\frac{b-a}{2n^2},$$it follows $\sqrt{n^2+b}-\sqrt{n^2+a}\sim\frac{b-a}{2n}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+a}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+b}}\sim\frac{b-a}{2n^3}$.

Comment: Remember that you could accept an answer (click the green checkmark) if you like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved without using L'Hopital rule. Indeed, notice that:

$$\left(\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+a}}-\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^2+b}}\right)=\frac{n^3(\sqrt{n^2+b}-\sqrt{n^2+a})}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}} = \\
= \frac{n^3(\sqrt{n^2+b}-\sqrt{n^2+a})(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a})}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a})} = \\
= \frac{n^3(n^2+b-n^2-a)}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a})} = \\
= (b-a)\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a})} =\\ 
= (b-a)\frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^4+(a+b)n^2+ab}(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a})} =\\
= (b-a)\frac{n^3}{n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{a+b}{n^2}+\frac{ab}{n^4}}\cdot n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)} =\\ 
= (b-a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a+b}{n^2}+\frac{ab}{n^4}}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)}.$$

As $n \to \infty$, then all terms in the form $\frac{\omega}{n^p}$, with $p \in \{2, 4\}$ tends to $0$. That is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (b-a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a+b}{n^2}+\frac{ab}{n^4}}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)} = (b-a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1} \cdot (\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1})} = \\=\frac{b-a}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Combine the fractions:$$\frac{n^3(\sqrt{n^2+b}-\sqrt{n^2+a})}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}}$$ Use L'Hopital: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^3(\sqrt{n^2+b}-\sqrt{n^2+a})}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3n^2\cdot\left(\sqrt{n^2+b}+\sqrt{n^2+a}\right)+n^3\cdot\left(\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{x^2+b}}+\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\right)}{\dfrac{-2n}{\sqrt{(n^2+a)(n^2+b)}}}$$ Now you could simplify the fraction and use L'Hopital again to get the answer.